# Automatic division of a Bezier curve with a given ratios

Tags: bezier-curves

I use a curve that serves as the cross section of a ring. Since I want to make not only solid coloured rings, but also 2 and 3 color rings, I want to divide the curve. However, I currently do this manually (ratios: 3: 1; 1: 4: 1; 1: 2: 1; etc., taking care of the dimensions). But with different types of cross sections, I would have to create it quite often and in several ways, which is a time consuming process.

E.g The following image shows what I would like to achieve.

[image]

So to do this, I want to ask for help on how to speed up creation instead of manual splitting.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curve Tools addon provides a multi subdivide tool that may help.
Under user preferences make sure *Add Curve: Curve Tools* addon is enabled.

In the *Edit* tab of the 3D View side bar there in the *Curve Edit* panel there is a Multisubdivide button.

It takes as parameters the percentage of curve segment length you want to place cuts at separated by spaces. For your example at $1:3:1$ you'd have five parts with $0.2$ factor so you need two cuts at `0.2 0.8`.

Beware this will measure length along the segment curvature, not in a straight line along an orthogonal axis.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I think it can quite speed up the work.